# ClosedXML when Working With Conditional Formats using formulas - the formula is incorrect

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using conditional formatting with ClosedXML and I am having 2 issues with it.  First, if I set the condition to be based on a value like so:

```
> RangeToAdd.AddConditionalFormat().WhenLessThan(0).Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red).Font.SetFontColor(XLColor.Red);
```

However, when I need to set it to a relative cell it is not working.  This is what I tried:

```
RangeToAdd.AddConditionalFormat().WhenLessThan("\"=RC[-19]\"").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Yellow);
RangeToAdd.AddConditionalFormat().WhenGreaterThan("\"=RC[-19]+RC[-18]+RC[-17]\"").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.BabyBlue);
```

and it is not working.  It is adding the ="= and then the formula which is not correct.  I followed what was said in the documentation [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Conditional-Formatting) and I tried it without escaping the quotes also.

The other issue is small but I cannot figure out.  How do I set a condition to stop when true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding too many quotes:  as per the documentation it's simply

```
WhenLessThan("=RC[-19]") // But Excel can't read it unfortunately
```

A possible work around

```
WhenLessThan("=" + RC(RangeToAdd,0,-19))
```

and similarly

```
WhenGreaterThan("=" + RC(RangeToAdd,0,-19) + "+" + RC(RangeToAdd,0,-18) + "+" + RC(RangeToAdd,0,-17))
```

using the helper

```
    static string RC(IXLRange range, int r, int c)
    {
        return range.FirstCell().CellBelow(r).CellRight(c).Address.ToString(XLReferenceStyle.A1);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that also and it didn't work. That creates an unreadable content error in the conditional formating

Comment: That works if, and only if, I know the Exact cell for the condition.  So if I put WhenLessThan("B2") then it works but when I use a relative reference it doesn't

Comment: You can enter =RC[-19] in excel if you turn on R1C1 style.